# "Off by one error" while using istringstream in C++

Tags: c++, istringstream

I get an off by one error while executing the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    string tokens,input;
    input = "how are you";
    istringstream iss (input , istringstream::in);
    while(iss){
        iss >> tokens;
        cout << tokens << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

It prints out the last token "you" twice, However if I make the following changes everything works fine.

```
 while(iss >> tokens){
    cout << tokens << endl;
}
```

Can anyone explain me how is the while loop operating. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is correct. The condition `while(iss)` fails only *after you read past the end of the stream*. So, after you have extracted `"you"` from your stream, it will still be true.

```
while(iss) { // true, because the last extraction was successful
```

So you try to extract more. This extraction fails, but does not affect the value stored in `tokens`, so it is printed again.

```
iss >> tokens; // end of stream, so this fails, but tokens sill contains
               // the value from the previous iteration of the loop
cout << tokens << endl; // previous value is printed again
```

For this very reason, you should always use the second approach you show. In that approach, the loop will not be entered, if the read was unsuccessful.